# @Test method in Scala trait not found

Tags: scala, junit4, scalatest, traits, scala-ide

does somebody know why **@Test** annotated **methods** which are **inherited** from a Scala trait are **not found** by the JUnit 4 test runner? It gives me "No JUnit tests found".

```
class FooTests extends BarTesting
```

But the following modification works?

```
import junit.framework.TestCase

class FooTests extends TestCase with BarTesting
```

In the Scala trait BarTesting I defined methods with the following signature.

```
@Test
final def testBar() {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: How are you running your tests?  It may be an issue with the IDE rather than the test runner: http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=62087&tstart=0.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I try to run it through Eclipse JEE Indigo Release together with the Scala IDE 2.0.0.beta9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Eclipse. You can raise as such if you like. http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets.

When you extend TestCase the test is being run because it starts with test, not because of the annotation. There was a problem with recognition of annotations, which is how the junit stuff works, and I haven't looked to see if it is fixed yet to make the junit stuff work.

Your best bet is to:

1. Raise the bug against scala-ide
2. Add @RunWith[classOf[JUnit]) to your class

The following works:

```
trait BarTesting {
  @Test final def testBar() {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnit4])
class FooTesting extends BarTesting {
}
```

And I'll try and fix the bug.

EDIT: In the latest versions of scala-ide (as of 9 November 2011), this now works.